# How can we detect web elements of a website built with react components which does not have html tag (to work with selenium C#)?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```js
 // Navigate to Account Managemnt window
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='module-menu']/div/button")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);            
            chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='module-menu']/div/div/button[2]")).Click();
            //*[@id="module-menu"]/div/div/button[2]
            Thread.Sleep(20000);

            IWebElement body = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
            var result = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            IWebElement Single_Acc_Add = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='single-add-button']/button/span"));
            //chrome_driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("+ Add")).Click();
            action.MoveToElement(Single_Acc_Add).Build().Perform();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>PCR Universe</title>
 <link href="/static/css/main.ed365ca1.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div
      id="GLOBAL_INFO"
         data-envvar="-siteminder" 
         data-clientname="universal-dashboard" 
         data-clientid="3027d708-26a2-4b63-a131-d672617f46f4" 
         data-domain="azurewebsites.net"  
         data-apienvvar="-siteminder" 
         data-apiname="universalwidgetservice" 
         data-apidomain="azurewebsites.net" 
     data-LOGINURL="https://universal-dashboard-siteminder.azurewebsites.net/authorize"
      data-LOGOUTURL= './Logout.html'
      data-ERRORPAGE= './LoginError.html'
      data-ENCODEDCOOKIE= 'false'
      data-USETOKENAUTH= 'false'
      >
        </div>
    
        <noscript>
          You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        </noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.84c386bd.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am working with selenium and came across a website which is not created with java script but react elements, how can i detect IWebElement when there are no html tags. Not able to detect them with link Text as well.

Comment: If there is no HTML tags , then what do you mean by "Not able to detect them with link Text as well." Please share your code trials , error trace if any.

Comment: looks like it is accessing the elements from another database and only website header has html tag as mentioned above, apart from that there are many other buttons and text boxes

Comment: As you have shared the HTML,  what code you have written is required for diagnosis purpose. What is your desirability?

Comment: I have shared Selenium C# code. The Web element "Single_Acc_Add" is not being detected.
And HTML code which i have shared is Web page Source Code